How do I get my Macbook Pro to stop trying to erase an iPhone that isn't connected or even turned on?
My Macbook Pro (M1 2020, running Sonoma 14.7) has been showing this in Finder for the last 30 minutes.  The iPhone has been disconnected and is turned off, but Finder thinks it is still in the process of erasing it.  How do I make this stop?


Do you want to erase the phone, or did you start to erase it by mistake? Have you tried quitting the Finder?

@LincDavis I do want to erase the phone, but it doesn't seem to be working. Yes, I tried relaunching Finder -- but it remains as shown.

What happened when you tried to erase it? Is it still bootable, and if so, can you erase it in the Settings app? If not that, can you get it into DFU mode? You might have to log out or restart the Mac to get rid of that dialog. See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/116940
